# There is an offset while opening a new window

Tags: wpf

I have the mouse pointer location from

```
Point loc = PointToScreen(Mouse.GetPosition(this));
new SecondWindow() { Owner = this, Left = loc.X, Top = loc.Y }.ShowDialog();
```

to get X and Y coordinates. I have to open the new window at the exact position of the mouse, but there is a very very noticeable offset for both Left and Top Properties of the window startup location.

Any idea or/and solution why is it happening??

Comment: I guess you don't properly manage DPI stuff. It's quite onerous but you can find tons of tips in SO.

Comment: Can you provide some code ? *same location* is vague, is it the top left corner or the center of the new window ? the same location as what ? The cursor ?

Comment: If the monitor's DPI is 100% and it is primary one, OP's code will mostly work. But it is not always the case.